# How to get index.html in django example?

Tags: python, django

I have a simple urls.py file:

```
 (r'^(.*.html)$','django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': ROOT + '/media/html/'})
```

How to get index.html file for url: http:/myserver.com/ ?

Comment: Follow the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something)

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your `urls.py`

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'index.html'}),     
)
```

I am assuming you want a static redirect to `index.html`. So this does it.

If you want to add dynamic content to it then you got to add a method in `views.py`.

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.3+ you can also use a class-based generic view:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
)
```